# Django model aggregate sum and count at same time

Tags: django, count, sum, aggregate, django-2.0

So I have a query like

```
SELECT sum(project_shares) as shares, count(*) as count FROM vv_projects
```

Is there any syntax like below in django 2.0

```
Projects.objects.aggregrate(Sum('project_shares'),Count('*'))
```

and output like

```
{'project_shares_sum':9,'count':8}
```

In django 2.0 count is used aggregate foreign key references so I am confused.
If not I have add another orm query line to get the count.

Comment: Did you try that syntax? Did it work? Would do you mean by "count is used aggregate foreign key references"?

Comment: New features in django 2.0
refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you provided should work. All you have to do is to replace `Count('*')` with `Count('id')` or `Count('pk')` to count all the entries.

```
Projects.objects.aggregrate(Sum('project_shares'), Count('pk'))
```

Output will be like:

```
{'project_shares__sum':9,'pk__count':8}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Both with pk and id. Thanks